# Printing from ejs Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I found [this](https://github.com/tojocky/node-printer) npm package that allows us to print stuff using Nodejs.

There are examples in the docs showing ways to print from the js file in the server

**print.js**

```
var printer = require("../lib");

printer.printDirect({data:"print from Node.JS buffer" // or simple String: "some text"
    //, printer:'Foxit Reader PDF Printer' // printer name, if missing then will print to default printer
    , type: 'RAW' // type: RAW, TEXT, PDF, JPEG, .. depends on platform
    , success:function(jobID){
        console.log("sent to printer with ID: "+jobID);
    }
    , error:function(err){console.log(err);}
});
```

I can then probably run `npm printer.js` for printing

I however, want to use this from my ejs template. When a user presses a button to print for example. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This package can be run from Node.js only so you can't put this code into browser's JS directly. However, you can create an HTTP(S) Node.js server which will trigger printing when a user sends HTTP request from your web page.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible because the EJS only processes templates when they are requested and then sends them to the client as text. When the client's browser get the server side rendered HTML file, it is not aware of the processing that went behind and is totally unaware of server side logic.

To achieve a print when a client clicks a button, you need to implement a route on the backend that would print data from a GET/POST body and implement logic to send the said request on the front end when the client clicks it.